# Recording window send command

Tags: c#, winapi, native

Every one who used native code knows that there are 2 interesting functions
`int FindWindow(String className, String windowName);
SendMessage(int window,...);`

How can you record any kind of actions, any sendmessage?

If you know Girder has a option to record event to be repeated when you press a button from the remote control.
This is actually a recorder of events that happen to you Operating system.

http://www.promixis.com/img/girder_3.png
 http://ww1.prweb.com/prfiles/2005/09/09/283149/Girderscreencapture.jpg

After this I want to know how can send mouseClick to a window, as you can see this can register left click, command as int (which can be sent to SendMessage).

Comment: Are you asking about message hooks? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms644960.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I've found window inspector and spy++

Answer (score 0):

In winForms you have access to the message cue, when you override WndProc

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Af few things to get you might find usefull

- GetCursorPos / SetCursorPos ([pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net))
- WM_LBUTTONDOWN / WM_LBUTTONUP (in SendMessage)